# Spring can be used in Seam?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, seam

I understand that Spring has really nice features, such as dependency injection. I am new to Spring. I have understood that I can use Spring alongside with struts and other frameworks too, in order to use its capabilities.

In my project I am going to use Seam 2.0, I am using JNDI to lookup for the EJBs. I am wondering if I can integrate Spring with Seam and use its ApplicationContext in order to get beans from that directly and not use JNDI lookup anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a whole chapter in the Seam reference dedicated to this:

> [27. Spring Framework integration](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html/spring.html)